# env variable in /etc/ld.so.conf

Tags: bash, scripting, libraries, etc

I've created a test.conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ folder with written:

`TEST_PATH=/path/To/My/Parent/Folder`

In my /etc/ld.so.conf I've added instead:

```
$TEST_PATH/mylib1 
$TEST_PATH/mylib2
$TEST_PATH/mylibN
```

When I do a ldconfig however it seems not working. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/ld.so.conf` and the files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` are not shell scripts. They just contain one directory name per line. You can't use shell constructs like `$TEST_PATH`. You have to write the full path.

Comment: damn, this is not a good news.. thanks to let me know though